# Finding the variance of this uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}$ for $0 \leq x \leq \theta$. Let $X_{(n)} = \text{max}(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, where $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. Then we want to find $V(X_{(n)})$. I feel like I have the answer but mine differs from my professors, so if someone could point out where I went wrong that would be immensely helpful.

We can find the PDF of $X_{(n)}$ by using the following trick: by definition, the CDF of $X_{(n)}$ is $P(X_{(n)} \leq x)$. However, if the maximum is less than or equal to x, then it follows that all $X_i$ are less than or equal to $x$, and so we have $P(X_{(n)} \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq n, \ldots, X_n \leq n)$. Since the $X_i$ are i.i.d, we have $P(X_{(n)} \leq x) = (F(x))^{n}$, where $F(x)$ denotes the CDF of $f(x)$. Note that the CDF of $f(x)$ is 
$$F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\theta} dy = \frac{y}{\theta} \bigg|_{y=0}^x = \frac{x}{\theta}.$$
Substituting this in, we have that then $P(X_{(n)} \leq x) = \frac{x^n}{\theta^n}$, and by taking the derivative we have that the PDF is $\frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}$. By a lemma, we may note that $V(X_{(n)}) = \mathbb{E}(X_{(n)}^2) - \mathbb{E}(X_{(n)})^2.$ Hence, we need to then find $\mathbb{E}(X_{(n)}^2)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_{(n)})^2$.

To find $\mathbb{E}(X_{(n)})$, we must solve the integral $$\int_0^{\theta} x \frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}dx = \int_0^{\theta} \frac{nx^{n}}{\theta^n}dx = \frac{nx^{n+1}}{(n+1)\theta^n} \bigg|_{x=0}^{\theta} = \frac{n\theta}{n+1}.$$
To find $\mathbb{E}(X_{(n)}^2)$, we must solve the integral
$$\int_0^{\theta} x^2 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}dx = \int_0^{\theta} \frac{nx^{n+1}}{\theta^n}dx = \frac{nx^{n+2}}{(n+2)\theta^n} \bigg|_{x=0}^{\theta} = \frac{n \theta^2}{n+2}.$$
Using the prior lemma, we have
$$V(X_{(n)}) = \mathbb{E}(X_{(n)}^2) - \mathbb{E}(X_{(n)})^2 = \frac{n \theta^2}{n+2} - \bigg(\frac{n\theta}{n+1} \bigg)^2 $$
$$=\frac{n\theta^2}{n+2} - \frac{n^2\theta^2}{n^2+2n+1} = \frac{n\theta^2(n^2+2n+1)-n^2\theta^2(n+2)}{(n+2)(n+1)^2} $$
$$=\frac{n^3\theta^2+2n^2\theta^2+n\theta^2-n^3\theta^2-2n^2\theta^2}{(n+2)(n+1)^2} = \frac{n\theta^2}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}.$$

However, my professor has $V(X_{(n)}) = \frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}$. Like I said, I don't know where I went wrong, so any help would be nice. Our expected value and PDF agree, so it must be somewhere in the calculation of variance.

Comment: How so? The n is a constant isn't it?

Comment: Sorry. I was confused. It is ok.

Comment: No worries. I'm pretty sure that part is correct since the answer matches up with his.

Comment: I agrree with your result. You can check the result here:   http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+n*t%5E2%2F(n%2B2)-(n*t%2F(n%2B1))%5E2   But it can be also seen by looking at your calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

We expect the following conditions to hold as the sample size is increased

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X_{(n)}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n\theta}{n+1} = \theta, \\ \lim_{n \to \infty} V(X_{(n)}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n\theta^2}{(n+1)(n+2)} = 0.$$

In other words the maximum statistic should approach the edge of the interval with diminishing dispersion as the sample size increases.

We also expect that as the length of the interval $\theta \to 0$, both the expected value and the variance of the maximum statistic should approach $0$. This will not happen if the variance is independent of $\theta.$

Comment: Ok, I'll have to let him know there's a typo. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Nice derivation.